Proving the complex projective line is homeomorphic to a sphere using gluing.
I’m reading Algebraic Geometry: A Problem Solving Approach and I’m confused on a few exercises designed to prove that the complex projective line is homeomorphic to a sphere in a coordinate-free manner.
First, they make you acknowledge that any point $(x:y)$ in $P(C)$ can be represented as $(1:x/y)$ or $(y/x:1)$ with the usual caveats or $x$ or $y$ not equaling zero.
Then they ask us to determine which points don’t have 2 representatives of the form $(x:1)=(1:1/x)$ (this is $(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$).
Next they say that we need two copies of C for the construction — U and V — and they ask us to show that $(x:1)$ to $(1:1/x)$ is a natural injection from U* to V*. Fine.
Next they say “a sphere can be split into a neighborhood of its northern and southern hemisphere. Show that a sphere can be obtained by gluing two copies of C together.”  Then they say ask us to put that construction together with the U-V mapping to show that P(C) is homeomorphic to a sphere.
Now I know you can glue two closed discs together to make a sphere. The only way I can see this construction working is by starting with the sphere, cutting it open along the equator, and associating the closed unit disk with the southern hemisphere and the complement of that area as the northern hemisphere, and possibly have the northern hemisphere be U and the southern be V.
Am I thinking about this correctly? It’s clear that the open disc is homeomorphic to C, but the northern hemisphere can’t be unless you add the point at infinity. I can’t quite figure out what to do with the circle $|z|=1$ or how to glue things up. Hints are appreciated.

Hint: they want you to glue $U$ and $V$ by appropriately glueing  $U^$ to $V^$ such that the origins of $U$ and $V$ become the north- and south-pole. Does that help?

Hi Ben - that’s what I thought out and sketched out in my proof — associate points with modulus greater than one with their inverses of modulus less than one. I just can’t figure out what’s happening at the equator. If you define U as (x:1) and V as (1:1/x), both points have (1:1), so that seems like a natural gluing point. Also I don’t get how you can glue 2 copies of C together to get a compact space. Clearly C as a plane is homeomorphic to the open disk, but you can’t add 2 open disks together and get a sphere.

If you remove just the north pole from a sphere, you are left with a space homeomorphic to an open disk. If you do this for each of the poles, you have two copies of open disk, and you may glue them along their overlap to get back the full sphere. Unlike gluing closed disks along their boundaries, the overlap will be a 2-dimensional open set (the open set excluding the two poles). Note that it is "split into a neighborhood of its northern and southern hemisphere"

Oh I see — they want you to double wrap the sphere. And then add back the poles. I didn’t think gluing implied completely pasting over. :)
